# SQL query to search first rows until sum = value and skip big value that can exceed the value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table

```
id | amount
---+--------
 1 |  500
 2 |  300
 3 |  750
 4 |  200
 5 |  500
```

I want to select rows ascending until the sum is 1000 or until all rows are searched (and skip a big value (750) that can exceed 1000).

How can I do query to return some rows like below?

Thanks for help

```
id | amount
---+--------
 1 |  500
 2 |  300
 4 |  200
```

Comment: What if sum of records are greater than 1000 or less than 1000?

Comment: if the next value makes the sum greater than 1000 then skip, if it's less than 1000 then sum it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need a common table expression for this.

The idea is to do a cumulative sum that skips the rows that would cause the sum to go above 1000 (aliased `sm` in the CTE), and to flag the records to skip (aliased `keep` in the CTE). Then the outer query just filters on the flag.

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 
        id, 
        amount, 
        case when amount > 1000 then 0 else amount end sm,
        case when amount > 1000 then 0 else 1 end keep
    from mytable 
    where id = 1
    union all
    select 
        t.id, 
        t.amount, 
        case when c.sm + t.amount > 1000 then c.sm else c.sm + t.amount end,
        case when c.sm + t.amount > 1000 then 0 else 1 end
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.id = c.id + 1
)
select id, amount from cte where keep = 1 order by id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ce813e50e512c4d74640bca3fcfb594d)**:

```
id | amount
-: | -----:
 1 |    500
 2 |    300
 4 |    200
```

Answer (score 1):

you should get the expected result using a recursively common table expression..

doing something like this..

```
with RECURSIVE yourtableOrdered as (select row_number() over (order by id) row_num, id, val from (values (1, 500), (2, 300), (3, 750), (4, 200), (5, 500)) V (id, val)),
lineSum as (
    select row_num, id, val, 
    case when val <= 1000 then val else 0 end totalSum, 
    case when val <= 1000 then true else false end InResult
    from yourtableOrdered
    where row_num = 1
    union all
    select y.row_num, y.id, y.val, 
    case when previousLine.totalSum + y.val <= 1000 then previousLine.totalSum + y.val else previousLine.totalSum end totalSum, 
    case when previousLine.totalSum + y.val <= 1000 then true else false end InResult
    from yourtableOrdered y
    inner join lineSum previousLine
    on y.row_num = previousLine.row_num + 1
),
yourExpectedResult as (
    select * from lineSum where InResult = true
)
select * from yourExpectedResult
```

see a working sample in

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cbcf/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(amount) over (order by id) as running_amount
      from t
     ) t
where running_amount - amount < 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't skip the 750 value yet. 
It returns 
1|500
2|300
3|750